# Import function from js file in a ts file (angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a JavaScript file that contains some functions, I want to import those functions in a ts file, I have tried using the technique below but it didn't work

```
import * as downloadExport from "./leaflet_export";
```

It raises the following error:

[image]

Any ideas about how to import functions from a js file into ts file??

Answer (score 2):

See documentation here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

> --allowJs boolean **false**(defacult value)   Allow JavaScript files to be compiled.